# Java/Python MD5 implementation- how to overcome unsigned 32-bit requirement?

Tags: java, python, md5, unsigned-integer

I'm attempting to implement MD5 (for curiosity's sake) in Python/Java, and am effectively translating the [wikipedia MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) page's pseudocode into either language. First, I used Java, only to encounter frustration with its negative/positive integer overflow (because unsigned ints aren't an option, `for-all integer,-2147483648 <= integer <= 2147483647`). I then employed Python, after deciding that it's better suited for heavy numerical computation, but realized that I wouldn't be able to overcome the unsigned 32-bit integer requirement, either (as Python immediately casts wrapped `int`s to `long`s).

Is there any way to hack around Java/Python's lack of `unsigned 32-bit integer`s, which are required by the aforementioned MD5 pseudocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note beforehand - I don't know if this is a *good* solution, but it appears to give the behaviour you want.

Using [the `ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), you can access the underlying low-level data-type directly, and hence have an unsigned int in Python.

Specifically, [`ctypes.c_uint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint):

```
>>> i = ctypes.c_uint(0)
>>> i.value -= 1
>>> i                                                            
c_uint(4294967295)
>>> i.value += 1
>>> i
c_uint(0)
```

This is arguably abuse of the module - it's designed for using C code easily from within Python, but as I say, it appears to work. The only real downside I can think of is that I assume `ctypes` is CPython specific.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the operations are bitwise operations, they wouldn't suffer from sign extension (which would cause you problems), except for right shift.

Java has a [`>>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) operator for this purpose.

Comment: +1.  People overestimate the difference between signed and unsigned arithmetic, and most operations will come out with the same result.